# Add DWR to SpringMVC,but there is no effective.When I access one Controller, throw an Error in console

Tags: spring-mvc, dwr

Add DWR to SpringMVC,but there is no effective.When I access one Controller, throw an Error in console.

LOG:
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
Warn: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/YouthDesign/reverseAjax/toPeopleTable] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springmvc'

web.xml

```html
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
 <display-name>Touth Design</display-name>
 
 <context-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>
   classpath*:/application-cfg.xml
  </param-value>
   </context-param>
   
   <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
   </listener>
   
   <servlet>
     <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
    classpath*:/springmvc-cfg.xml,
    classpath*:/dwr-cfg.xml
   </param-value>
     </init-param>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
<!--    <servlet>
     <servlet-name>dwr</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.spring.DwrSpringServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>activeReverseAjaxEnabled</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
     </init-param>
   </servlet> -->
   
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

springmvc-cfg.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.3.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.youthdesign.web">
  <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
 </context:component-scan>
 
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
 <!-- 映射静态资源 -->
 <mvc:resources location="/static/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
 
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
 </bean>

</beans>
```

dwr-cfg.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xmlns:spring-dwr="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr http://www.directwebremoting.org/schema/spring-dwr/spring-dwr-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">

 <spring-dwr:configuration />
 <spring-dwr:url-mapping />
 <spring-dwr:controller id="dwrController" debug="true">
  <spring-dwr:config-param name="activeReverseAjaxEnabled" value="true"/>
 </spring-dwr:controller>
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
     <property name="alwaysUseFullPath" value="true"/>
      <property name="mappings">
       <props>
          <prop key="/dwr/**/*">dwrController</prop>
       </props>
     </property>
    </bean>  
 <spring-dwr:annotation-scan base-package="com.youthdesign" scanDataTransferObject="true" scanRemoteProxy="true"/>  
  
</beans>
```

Above are my config files,please help,thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I have fix this problem.If you are learning dwr and want to use it with spring together.You can refer to my demo on Github.
https://github.com/BigRui/simpleDWR